# Why is a polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb F_p[x]$ determined by its value at all the points in $\text{Spec}(\mathbb F_p[x])$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Definition from Vakil: Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Elements $a ∈ A$ are called functions on $\text{Spec} A$, and their value at the point $P\in \text{Spec}(A)$ will be $a$ (mod $P$).

I want to prove that $f(x)\in \mathbb F_p[x]$ is determined by its value at all the points in $\text{Spec}(\mathbb F_p[x])$ but I don't know what kinds of points in $\text{Spec}(\mathbb F_p[x])$ I should use to test $f(x)$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just showing that the intersection of all the prime ideals in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ is $0$.

Comment: @anomaly Why? What theorems are we using here?

Comment: Just unravel the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If you want to lose as little information as possible when reducing mod $P$, you want $P$ to be small.  What's the smallest prime ideal in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$?

Comment: You mean those generated by linear polynomials? The value $f$ at $(x-k)$ is the same as $f(k)$, but $f$ can't be determined by its values in $\mathbb F_p$, right?

Comment: No, the prime ideal generated by a linear polynomial is actually quite large (it's a maximal ideal, for instance).  Can you think of any prime ideals that aren't maximal?

Comment: Oh...you meant $(0)$? So the statement in question is obviously true for any polynomial ring where (0) us a prime ideal?

Comment: Right, or any domain.